# Macbuntu Problem

Tags: chromebook, macbuntu

So I'm new to the whole Ubuntu thing, and I thought I would try to make my Toshiba Chromebook 2 look like a mac using this tutorial: http://lifehacker.com/5665765/macbuntu-makes-your-linux-desktop-look-like-mac-os-x
All went well till I typed in ./install.sh and it said "Permission Denied" does anyone know how to fix this? Or is this just not possible on my Chromebook?

Comment: Considering that the tutorial is more than 6 years old, I would tend to be cautious with it. A lot has changed since Lucid Lynx.

Comment: Do you know of a tutorial for Chromebooks that's newer? (Do I need one for Chromebooks specifically or does it not matter)

Comment: I would think that the Ubuntu version is more important than if it is for Chromebooks. I am not aware of any newer tutorials, though I have not searched.

Comment: Also the script checks the Ubuntu version and would not work on a supported version anyway. (kudos to the developer for this)

Comment: just stumbled across this one http://www.noobslab.com/2016/04/macbuntu-1604-transformation-pack-for.html

Answer (score 1):

You have to give "execution permission" to the script. Take a look on this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions

the command you need is `chmod +x install.sh`

Comment: i *think* it worked (it didnt deny your command) what do I do now?

Comment: Now try running `./install.sh` again.

Comment: bash: ./install.sh: Permission denied :(

Comment: execute `ls -l install.sh` and post its ouput please

Comment: -rwx--x--x 1 chronos chronos 29584 sep 10  2010 install.sh

Comment: try `sudo chmod +x install.sh` and then `./install.sh` again.

Comment: Permission denied

Comment: Try `sudo chmod 777 install.sh`

Comment: Permission denied again

Comment: I can't understand that. Anyway, I suggest you to find a newer tutorial for macbuntu as the one you posted seems to be a bit old (it talks about ubuntu 10.xx).

Comment: Okay, well thanks for your help anyway man, :)

Comment: I'm still interested in see why you are not able of running the script. Hope some advanced user coud explain this situation.